# Controlling servos with Raspberry Pi local server

Tags: webserver, embedded, raspberry-pi, dma, pwm

We are doing research into running a server on a Pi, and communicating with it via a webapp (over a local network) to control 2-3 servos. It appears that the Rpi has only one hardware configured PWM pin, but this can be worked around via servoblaster. However, since Servoblaster utilizes the Rpi's DMA, will it interfere with the Pi's ability to operate a web server? I apologize if this question is unclear i am somewhat unfamiliar with the software/network concepts involved. Additionally, is there a good resource for understanding the DMA function further?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do not you just use Software PWM?

Comment: How stable is software PWM with the CPU under load? We are considering adding more features to our system that would require additional processing.

Comment: If you care about processing power, Raspberry Pi is not the right tool. There are much more powerful alternatives with processors over 1 Ghz and 1 GB RAM

Comment: @ Brad F Servos don't usually require extremely precise timing. But the software PWM is run off interrupt routines, so the answer to your question depends on whether or not the additional processing disables interrupts.

Comment: @iTech Any suggestions on one of those alternatives maybe around $50?

Comment: @UncleO thanks for the reply. Im assuming that incoming network traffic is retrieved via interrupt?

Comment: I will write it as answer, to explain more

Comment: @BradF I don't know how networking works on Raspberry Pi, or if you are using an OS. I assume those interrupts won't run very long, so they won't disrupt your servo PWM substantially.

Answer (score 0):

You can control Servos using `Software PWM`, which will not require any further hardware or using `DMA`

If you care about performance and want more powerful hardware consider [ODROID-X](http://www.hardkernel.com/renewal_2011/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=g133999328931), it has 1.4GHz processor and 1GB RAM and cost $130, it is the best value for the price.

For other alternatives check [Small low cost linux pc's](https://raymii.org/s/articles/Small_Linux_PCs.html)